# Transitioning between two UIViewController stacks

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

I'm planning with my App to have a root `UIViewController` in the App Delegate, that basically branches off into a possible two `UIViewControllers`, each of those `UIViewControllers` will have a number of `UINavigationControllers` pushed onto of them, might have a `UITabBarController`, not too sure yet but the main issue is I want to from any view transfer from one `UIViewController` stack to the other, and maintain the view hierarchy.

When I want to change from one `UIViewController` stack to the other, I thought about calling the App delegate:

```
MainClass *appDelegate = (MainClass *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate.viewController someMethod];
```

and transitioning that way, but it seems a bit of a hacky way to do it. Also thought about passing a reference through the stack to the root `UIViewController` and call the method to change between the `UIViewControllers`.

Which way would be the better way? Or is there a way I haven't thought about that is the preferred way of doing it?

Comment: better use delegate to change from one vc stack to another, and to maintain the view hierarchy, pass the message through the hierarchy to the top of the stack, and let the top delegate to rootVC, then let the rootVC do the actual transition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you mean you have one root view controller and this root VC manages two view controllers and these two controllers manages many sub view controllers?

if so, you may try to use custom containment controller. and every time you want to change stack from one to another, just delegate to rootVC to do so.

```
- (void)moveToAnotherController:(UIViewController *)vc
{
    [self displayContentController:vc];
}

- (void)displayContentController:(UIViewController *)content
{
    [self addChildViewController:content];
    [self.view addSubview:content.view];
    [content.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];

}

//remove child controller from container
- (void)hideContentController:(UIViewController *)content animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [content willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [content.view removeFromSuperview];
    [content removeFromParentViewController];
}
```

Comment: in this way, you can custom your transition animation in the last two methods

Comment: How would you send the reference to the rootVC through the stack though?

Comment: use delegate to do so

Answer (score 1):

A `UITabBarController` offers you exactly that functionality. If you have one as your root view controller and two tabs with a navigation controller in each tab, then you're basically done. If you don't want to show the tab bar in the bottom you can just hide it and then trigger the tab switch from code following some events. It's pretty straight forward :)

Comment: I didn't think about that but you're right, though I do want some of the nice transitions you get from changing between view controllers (like flip and dissolve) which I'm pretty sure you don't get from a UITabBarController.